# Using CKEditor with Meteor

Tags: meteor, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor with meteor.

First I added the package

https://libraries.io/meteor/lsun:ckeditor

Then I added the following code:

route.js

```
Router.route('/editor', function () {
  this.render('editor');
});
```

editor.html

```
<template name="editor">
    <form>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
    </form>
</template>
```

helpers.js

```
Template.editor.rendered = function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 };
```

Now when I browse to my /editor route, I can see the ckeditor being loaded initially. However, if I press F5 while I am on the page, then I start getting the plain textarea, without ckeditor replacing it with the editor. Also, I get the following error in the javascript console:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
meteor.js:888 
ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
    at Template.editor.rendered (helpers.js:10)
    at blaze.js:3338
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js:3679)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js:3334)
    at null.<anonymous> (blaze.js:3427)
    at blaze.js:1788
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js:2219)
    at blaze.js:1787
    at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:531)
    at onGlobalMessage (meteor.js:373)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` from your console? Generally that error happens because ckeditor is called before it's loaded. Perhaps try https://github.com/DerMambo/wait-on-lib and just load ckeditor from a cdn.

Comment: Yes. Running this from the console works. Its probably a timing issue just like you mentioned. Even running it inside from a setTimeout also works in the template.

If I use the wait on lib, and load ckeditor from there, should I then remove lsun:ckeditor package?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done in the past.